# grid for plotly graph_objects?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

[image: tickers]

Hello,

I am trying to plot indicators for stocks with values from a dataframe on plotly graph_objects using subplots. Is there a way to iterate over row and column in order to set the indicator domain parameter for row and column variables?

I would very much like to make a grid without having to set the row and column index of the indicators manually because the data I'm working with is dynamic.

Please find the code and screenshot below.
Thank you!

```
fig = make_subplots(
rows=len(df),
cols=len(df.columns),
specs=[[{"type": "indicator"} for c in df.columns] for t in df.index],
)
number = 0

for i in range(len(df)):

  row = df.loc[i]
  name_i= row.loc['name'].replace('(CR)', '')
  ticker_i= row.loc['ticker'].replace('.AT', '')
  latest_price_i= row.loc['latest price'].round(2)
  change_i= row.loc['change']

  number += 1

  fig.add_trace(
    go.Indicator(
        mode="number+delta", 
        value= latest_price_i, 
        title = {"text": "<br><span style='font-size:0.7em;color:gray'> ({ticker})<br> {name} </span>".format(ticker= ticker_i,name= name_i)},
        delta = {'position': "bottom", 'reference': change_i, 'valueformat': ' %',   'relative': False},
        domain = {'row': 0, 'column': number}
        )
       )

fig.update_layout(
        grid = {'rows': 5, 'columns': 2, 'pattern': "independent"},
        margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=30, b=30)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @r-beginners

I have found a solution,
I hope this helps somebody with the same problem:

```
CHART_THEME = 'plotly_dark'  
fig = go.Figure()
fig.layout.template = CHART_THEME

grid_rows = len(df)//2+1 # ensures that the are always enough rowsfor the number of indicators
grid_cols = 2

grid= [[i, j] for i in range(grid_rows) for j in range(grid_cols)]
grid = grid[0:df.shape[0]]

for i,n,ticker in zip(grid, df.index, df.index):

  name_i= df['name'].values[n].replace('(CR)', '')
  ticker_i= df['ticker'].values[n].replace('.AT', '')
  latest_price_i= df['latest price'].values[n]
  old_price_i= df['old price'].values[n]

  fig.add_trace(
    go.Indicator(
        number = {'prefix': "€ " },
        mode="number+delta", 
        value= latest_price_i,
        title = {"text": "<br><span style='font-size:0.7em;color:gray'> ({ticker}) <br> {name} </span>".format(ticker= ticker_i,name= name_i)},
        delta = {'position': "bottom", 'reference': old_price_i , 'valueformat': '.2', 'relative': True},
        domain={'row': i[0], 'column': i[1]},
        
      )
  )

fig.update_layout(
  autosize=True,
  height=600,
  width=500,
  margin=dict(l=0,r=0,t=20,b=0),
  grid = {'rows': grid_rows, 'columns': grid_cols, 'pattern': "independent"}
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The data used for the code was obtained from the stock prices of 10 well-known companies for the last two days. The index for the loop process is a matrix array with 5 rows and 2 columns, assuming a graph of 5 rows and 2 columns in advance.
For the data frame in wide format, the data is put into the loop process column by column. The indicator is adapted to your setup. If the layout information is the same as the matrix, some stock prices will be overlaid. I have added one additional row to make 6 rows. We do not know the cause.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = "AAPL GOOG MSFT TSLA NFLX META AMD AMZN DIS AAA"
data = yf.download(tickers, start="2022-10-11", end="2022-10-13", interval='1d')
df = data.Close
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)

df[df.columns[:4]]
    AAA     AAPL    AMD     AMZN
Date                
2022-10-11  24.129999   138.979996  57.630001   112.209999
2022-10-12  24.110001   138.339996  57.849998   112.900002

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

col_idx = [1,2]*5 
row_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(1,6), 2)

fig = go.Figure()

for r,c,ticker in zip(row_idx, col_idx, df.columns):
    #print(c,r,ticker)
    fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        mode='number+delta',
        value=df[ticker][0],
        delta={'reference': (df[ticker][1])},
        title=ticker,
        domain={'row': int(r), 'column': int(c)}
    ))
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    height=600,
    width=500,
    margin=dict(l=0,r=0,t=20,b=0),
    grid = {'rows': 6, 'columns': 3, 'pattern': "independent"})
```